# Issue deploying Django/websocket/redis project to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, websocket, redis, django-channels

I have a Django project, which is running fine on my machine, that uses redis and a couple of workers to utilize websockets and give constantly updated subway times. It works fine on my machine, but I'm logging errors like such on Heroku when I have it deployed:

```
2021-03-25T04:23:19.462596+00:00 app[worker2.1]: [2021-03-25 04:23:19,462: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.. Trying again in 32.0 seconds...
2021-03-25T04:23:51.493083+00:00 app[worker2.1]: [2021-03-25 04:23:51,492: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.. Trying again in 32.0 seconds...
2021-03-25T04:22:11.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-concentric-76659 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.23 sample#load-avg-5m=0.51 sample#load-avg-15m=0.42 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.061111 sample#memory-total=15629040kB sample#memory-free=7601200kB sample#memory-cached=3699616kB sample#memory-redis=326704bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
2021-03-25T04:24:23.524980+00:00 app[worker2.1]: [2021-03-25 04:24:23,524: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.. Trying again in 32.0 seconds...
```

I've installed and started redis via heroku run bash and the ports are correct.  What could be the problem? If there is any info that would be helpful I am happy to update.

UPDATE TO ADD DETAILS FROM SETTINGS.PY:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [env('REDIS_URL')]
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE TO ADD PROCFILE CODE:

```
web: daphne main_app.wsgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: celery -A main_app worker -l INFO
beat: celery -A main_app beat -l INFO
```

Comment: Have you used the `heroku-redis` add-on on heroku? Also can you share what settings you did for the redis server in your settings.py file?

Comment: @AjayLingayat yes, I am using heroku-redis add-on.  I've updated the post with what I believe is the relevant code you're asking for.  Let me know if there's anything else I should share. many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Update the procfile with the following code.

**Procfile**

```
web: daphne <Project Name>.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
chatworker: python manage.py runworker --settings=<Project Name>.settings -v2
```

Also check if `daphne` is listed in your `requirements.txt` file. If not then add it with any version equal to or greater than `3.0.1`.

Comment: I updated to include my current procfile text. Your recommended snippet cites asgi server, but with Django Channels, I believe this should be a wsgi project, correct?  Should I be adding your chatworker code to the end of my procfile or supplanting one of my celery workers?

Comment: You could give it a try.